# Add Input Mask for Phone Number

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning

I have a Lightning input field for a phone number:

```
<lightning:input type="tel" label="Phone number" name="phoneNumber"/>
```

I want to display a mask in the input field so the phone number is automatically formatted as the user types. E.g., area code added inside parenthesis, dash added as a separator:

```
Ex: (207) 555-1000
```

Is there an out-of-the-box solution for this? If not, how might this be accomplished?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The lightning input tag comes with a pattern matching attribute so you can format it on the fly like so:

```
<lightning:input type="tel" label="Phone field with pattern matching" name="phone3" value="343-343-3434" pattern="[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{4}"/>
```

Alternatively, if you want a custom solution for this, use the onchange attribute to call a function from your controller that takes the value on the component and then formats it appropriately.